# How do you add an onload event to a view in Zend Framework

Tags: jquery, actionscript-3, zend-framework

I tried the following:

```
$this->view->pagedata['body'] = "onload='purchase_ajax_init();'";
```

But just keep getting:

```
Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property Zend_View::$view has no effect in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\ljj\application\views\scripts\purchase\create.phtml on line 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know that simply assigning the onload string to the body member of the pagedata property does not affect the html body tag, the following will work:

```
$this->view->pagedata = array();
$this->view->pagedata['body'] = 'onload="purchase_ajax_init();"';
```

You need to make sure that the pagedata property is an array before adding items to it.  I do not understand why this is the case; hopefully somebody will enlighten us...

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I put this kind of thing directly in the `<body>` tag of my layout or view script. Just because you are using Zend Framework doesn't mean you have to use it for everything. I am a big fan of keeping things simple.

So, just to clarify, in your layout or view script you would have

```
<body 'onload="purchase_ajax_init();"'>
```